# Petroleum Benzine or Normal-Hexane for removing a silicone based adhesive?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I’m trying to remove the glass panel wich is glued to the polarizer of an LCD display (an Apple iMac display with broken glass but working LCD wich I would like to repurpose).

It seems to be fixed with a soft, non-curing, silicone-based adhesive . But the process of removing it is terribly tedious and I was wondering if there was a solvent that might help me.

LG, the manufacturer states in the display's data sheet that touches from bare hands, grease, some cosmetics, acetone, alcohol and toluene will harm the polarizer‘s surface.

Some people claim that they removed the glass successfully using baby oil but given that info from the data sheet I'm not sure if the oil may be harmful to the polarizer.

LG recommends to use petroleum benzine or normal-hexane for cleaning the polarizer surface.

Now, my question is if one of these two might be a helpful substance for the task of dissolving/weakening the silicon adhesive and removing the glass?

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to ask Louis Rossmann:)

Comment: Yeah, though isn't he more an electronics guy?